# How do I add another dbus service file search directory?

Tags: software-installation, d-bus

I've built an application which defines a dbus service. I've installed the app under `/opt/myapp`, and I now have a file named `/opt/myapp/share/dbus-1/services/whatever.MyApp.service` .

Now, I suppose if I copied that to reside under `/usr/local/share/dbus-1/services`, that might work. But what I would rather do is add the `/opt/myapp/share/dbus-1/services` to the services lookup path. How do I do that?

PS - In case it matters, I use Devuan.

Answer (score 1):

from `man dbus-daemon`

> A message bus daemon has a configuration file

> The standard systemwide and per-session message bus setups are configured in the files "/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf" and "/usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf". These files normally <include> a system-local.conf or session-local.conf in /etc/dbus-1; you can put local overrides in those files to avoid modifying the primary configuration files.

> The configuration file is an XML document.

> The following elements may be present in the configuration file.

> <servicedir>
> Adds a directory to search for .service files, which tell the dbus-daemon how to start a program to provide a particular well-known bus name. See the D-Bus Specification for more details about the contents of .service files.

> <standard_session_servicedirs/> requests a standard set of session service directories. Its effect is similar to specifying a series of  elements for each of the data directories, in the order given here.

Comment: Why is the main configuration file under `/usr/share` rather than under `/etc` ? Peculiar...